# turn off mobile after some time when done factory reset

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, recovery-mode, factory-reset, android-device-manager

I lost my data from [**android device manager**](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) app from web. I have mistakenly click erase button in web.

I have wipe data factory reset in **samsung s2 i9100** using **ClockworkMod Recovery** ([Process](http://chaladi.me/tag/samsung-galaxy-s2-not-going-to-recovery-mode/)).
Done, succesfully  and open my mobile .but after some time (1 min to 3 min) it switch off my mobile.

First i have done using root kernel: **Siyah-s2-v6.0b4.tar** first then recovery([Process](http://donandroid.com/root-i9100jhls4-use-siyah-s2-v6-0b4-tar-to-root-galaxy-s2-4-1-2-jhls4-822.)).

Any problem of my devices. or Any idea how to get my data working condition. or Any other method in **ClockworkMod Recovery** to get recovery data. please waiting your response.

**Now**: *

> My Mobile charging successfully, but when press power on button, i
>   have saw only samsung splash screen. notheing further my mobile go or
>   doesn't open my mobile.

*

Comment: As you're mentioning CWM: Have you made a Nandroid backup before that accident happened? If so, and the backup being at least half-way up-to-date, you could restore that – which should bring the device into exactly the state it was when you've created the backup (as Nandroid "images" all partitions).

Comment: No , i have not no any backups? Ok if i don't get data recovery. So can i simple start fresh new mobile os. it means, sacrifice all data . I just want to simply run my mobile. would you suggest any idea?

Comment: No backup = no restore, sorry (should always be the first thing to do after installing CWM: Make a Nandroid backup!). And all that could be done, has been done by hitting that button. But try again: Enter CWM, do a factory-reset, wipe cache, wipe data (thought the latter two are just repeating the former, it cannot hurt). Flash another ROM, try without tampering with the "special kernel" (which also could be the cause). Switch on USB debug, and immediately start `adb debug` from your PC to hopefully catch the event issuing the shutdown.